# Calculation using contracted Binachi identity

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Let $(M,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional complete Riemannian manifold. Consider the following equation
$$\tag{1} s=nc+\Delta f,$$
where $s$ is the scalar curvature, $c$ is any real number and $f\in C^2(M)$. It is given that by using contracted Binachi identity, the above equation implies that
$$\tag{2} |\nabla f|^2+s+2cf=A_0,$$
for some constant $A_0$. I can not get the intermediate steps. Please help me to under stand this proof.

The above is found in p.376 of this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123606002680).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the context of [Ricci soliton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_soliton) and (2) is a well-known formula proved by Hamilton which follows from the Ricci soliton equation instead of (1). The proof can be found in Lemma 1.1 in this [survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.2006.pdf). For completeness I'll record the proof here:

The Ricci soliton equation is 
$$\tag{3} \operatorname{Rc} = c g + D^2 f,$$
or $R_{jk} = cg_{jk} + f_{jk}$. Taking covariant derivative to (3) and commuting the derivatives, 
\begin{align}\nabla _i R_{jk} &= \nabla _i f_{jk} \\
&= \nabla_j f_{ik} + R_{ijk}^l \nabla_l f \\
&= \nabla_j R_{ik}+R_{ijk}^l \nabla_l f.
\end{align}
Taking the trace on $j$ and $k$, and using the [contracted second Bianchi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contracted_Bianchi_identities), 
$$\nabla_i s = \nabla^j R_{ij} - R^l_i \nabla_l f  = \frac 12 \nabla_i s - R^l_i \nabla_l f.$$
Thus $\nabla _i s = -2 R_{i}^l \nabla_l f$. So 
\begin{align}
\nabla_i(|\nabla f|^2+s+2cf) &= 2f_{ji} \nabla_j f + \nabla_i s + 2c\nabla_ i f \\
&= 2(R_{ij} -c g_{ij}) \nabla_j f - 2R_{ij} \nabla _j f + 2c \nabla_i f = 0.
\end{align}

Thus $|\nabla f|^2+s+2cf$ is constant.